# Is it possible to create template only for one page of given type (i.e. one particular product category for Woocommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

As in question:

is it possible, to define template for all (ie.) product categories in Wocommerce, but display this unique template only for one particular category?

Comment: Yes you can. Read more about wordpress templates here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ . How to create templates for Woo - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ . There are other ways to remove or add something to specific category using the hooks too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Elementor templates if you have Elementor Pro you can do this.

Go to Elementor > Theme Builder > Product archive. Create the template and in display conditions select the category archive where you want to display the template.

If you're already using Elementor Pro and you have a product archive template already, make sure to exclude the category that uses the other template by adding an additional condition.